# Determining Type of Adhesive for Edge of New Countertop

Tags: adhesive, kitchen-counters, countertops

[image: counter]
[image: edge]

I'd like to re-adhere the edge of this countertop to the counter. In searching for an answer, I found [this post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/180104/how-to-fix-detachment-of-counter-top-laminate/180106#180106) where it was recommended that a. the edge be taken completely off prior to re-adhering with contact cement and b. the person would want to invest in new countertops soon.

For context, these countertops were installed roughly two months ago and there doesn't seem to be any damage otherwise. The homeowner (a friend) hired a general contractor to do their kitchen remodel and it was finished in late December. The friend and I are also caregivers to a relative in home hospice here, so I don't need the fix to be perfect - but I'd rather not make it worse by using gorilla glue, etc. For now, I'm holding it together with painter's tape. To be honest, it probably became loose due to that being a narrow passageway for clumsy (myself included) people.

Finally, I would feel comfortable removing the strip; however, I don't see obvious strips of glue, wavy lines, etc. and I've never used contact cement so I wasn't sure if it spreads evenly. I'm happy to look up how to use it in the event that is the proper adhesive to use in this case.

Thank you in advance for any and all replies!

Comment: The stuff making up most counter tops does not like any water, so reglueing the edge back on is good.  Contact cement is a very thick liquid, so it does spread if you help

Comment: @crip659 - To clarify, you're suggesting I remove the entire edge? And if so, would I need to strip the glue, or would completely covering both surfaces with contact cement be good enough? The linked post implied that contact glue might work as a solvent as well. Thank you!

Comment: I would not force the piece off.  If it peels off easy, remove the whole piece.  If not spread the contact cement as far down as you can and press the the piece back on.

Comment: Thank you so much @crip659 I appreciate you taking the time to help!

Comment: You can use a sharp toothpick to poke glue into the joint, if the piece won't come all the way off.